# SSL communication to support CA Certificate(Public key certificate)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, ca

For the SSL communication with the certificate for the below C/C++ code link how to support the CA certificate (public key certificate which is exported from the site info)

[HttpClientWithSslAndClientCert](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/WebServices/HttpClientWithSslAndClientCert/cpp/HttpClientWithSslAndClientCert.cpp)

```
WS_SSL_TRANSPORT_SECURITY_BINDING sslBinding = {}; // zero out the struct
sslBinding.binding.bindingType = WS_SSL_TRANSPORT_SECURITY_BINDING_TYPE; // set the binding type

// Set up the client certificate. The certificate must have been registered beforehand.
static const WS_STRING certStore = WS_STRING_VALUE(L"My");
static const WS_STRING certSubjectName = WS_STRING_VALUE(L"CN=client.com");

WS_SUBJECT_NAME_CERT_CREDENTIAL certBySubject;
certBySubject.credential.credentialType = WS_SUBJECT_NAME_CERT_CREDENTIAL_TYPE;
certBySubject.storeLocation = CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER;
certBySubject.storeName = certStore;
certBySubject.subjectName = certSubjectName;
sslBinding.localCertCredential = &certBySubject.credential;

// declare and initialize the array of all security bindings
WS_SECURITY_BINDING* securityBindings[1] = { &sslBinding.binding };
```

For the above sample code with my CA certificate (Public key certificate exported from site info) I am getting error:

> There was an error communicating with the endpoint at 'https://localhost:8444'.
> **No credentials were available in the client certificate**"

How to support the CA certificate for the SSL communication?

I am able to establish a communication with the certificate with private keys.

how to support / code changes to add the properties to support the CA certificate/ public certificate.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish by using "CA certificate" as a client certificate. Client certificate is expected to be used to authenticate client instead of or in addition to usual password authentication, so it should be personal certificate with private key, not CA certificate.

Comment: Hi,
I want to establish a SSL communication with "CA certificate", so what changes has to be done to support the SSL communication with CA Certificate, where this CA certificate is sent to server in SSL handshake

Comment: Why you want to use CA certificate as a client certificate? what are you trying to accomplish? Client certificate can be composed to include entire CA certificate chain that has issued it, so CA certificate will be a part of client certificate. but you cannot just use CA certificate as a client certificate.

Comment: Hi @dewaffled,
Thank you for the replay,
I am trying to include/send this CA certificate from client to server in SSL communication, 
I have only this CA certificate for the connection establishment, is it possible to achieve this? 
if Yes, how can we achieve.
if No, any other approach.

I am also exploring more on this, but didn't get proper info, please suggest to understand.

Comment: Hi, I found this CA certificate cannot be used for the client certificate.
------------------------------------
I need one more clarification, is the above code supports server authentication in client side (SSL handshake) Please suggest.

Comment: You may open an incident at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support/?tabs=Contact-us so that our engineer can work with you closely and please choose the 'Networking Development - Other' for Windows SDK for this issue.